# How to check if the fxml window or a stage is open or not in JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, scene, stage

I am working with several FXML files that are activated by pressing a button from the Main Frame. When you click the button more than once, more than one instance of the stage opens up, so it is taking too much memory (RAM) and the program becomes too slow.

**Is it there any way to check if the needed stage is already launched, so jump to the opening window or give a warning message and not opening the same stage again in javafx ?**

Comment: You could use [isShowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#isShowing--), but why not just check if you’ve created your stage already?

Comment: i tried but not workng i did it like this _{ if(!stage.isShowing){ stage.show()}}_

Comment: You've need to store the the state in some kind of data structure. E.g. `Map<URL, Stage>`, which would allow you to retrieve a existing `Stage`, if one has been created and show the stage...